# Design alternative for access to derived class member from base class pointer

Tags: c++, design-patterns, inheritance, derived-class, crtp

I'm writing a DAL/ORM library. This library will be accessed mainly from GUIs but also from some "business level" applications. I'm still in the design phase of this library and came to a point where I'm not sure how to solve the following issue nicely.

In my current design I have a class, let's call it `List` for the moment, that has a container of another class, `Properties`. Properties come in two flavors (A and B), with mostly the same functionality, but some of their functionality is different. Furthermore both flavors of `Properties` store values. Values can be of different data types, including, but not limited to, PODs. Each `List` can contain a certain `Property` only once and `Properties` are identified by a "name", i.e. a string.

I now want to be able to do all of the following:

- Keep the complexity of the interface as low as possible
- Iterate over all `Properties` in `List`, and call methods that both `Property` flavors support.
- When having an instance of a `Property`, accessing its value in a type safe way
- If possible, avoid `dynamic_cast` or similar constructs

So, obviously pure polymorphism cannot do the trick here. I have done some experiments with the *curiously recurring template pattern* and with *composition* of two class hierarchies - one for `Properties` and one for their values (example code below). However, so far I did not succeed in getting a design that fulfilled all my requirements.

The basic design (i.e. which classes exist, how they are organized etc.) is not fixed and could be easily changed. I am still in the design phase of this project, so only test code exists. However, the basic idea has to bee like explained above (i.e. that a `List` has `Properties` which in turn have `values`).

Any solutions to my problems or raw ideas, thoughts, etc. are highly appreciated.

---

Example code for hierarchy implementation. Obviously I will not be able to access a property's value in a type-safe way here.

```
class PropertyValue {
public:
    virtual std::string GetAsString() const = 0;

    bool IsReadOnly() const { return m_isReadOnly; }
    void IsReadOnly(const bool val) { m_isReadOnly = val; }

protected:
    PropertyValue(PropertyValue & other) : m_isReadOnly(other.m_isReadOnly)
    {};

    PropertyValue(bool readOnly) : m_isReadOnly(readOnly)
    {};

private:
    bool m_isReadOnly;
};

class StringValue : public PropertyValue {
private:
    typedef std::string inner_type;
public:
    StringValue(const inner_type & value, bool readOnly) : PropertyValue(readOnly)
                                                         , m_value(value)
    {};

    StringValue(StringValue & other) : PropertyValue(other.IsReadOnly())
                                     , m_value(other.m_value)
    {};

    std::string GetAsString() const { return m_value; };

    inner_type GetValue() const { return m_value; };
    void SetValue(const inner_type & value) { m_value = value; };

    unsigned int GetMaxLenght() const { return m_maxLength; };

private:
    inner_type m_value;
    unsigned int m_maxLength;
};

class IntValue : public PropertyValue {
private:
    typedef int inner_type;
public:
    IntValue(const inner_type & value, bool readOnly) : PropertyValue(readOnly)
                                                      , m_value(value)
    {};

    IntValue(IntValue & other) : PropertyValue(other.IsReadOnly())
                               , m_value(other.m_value)
    {};

    std::string GetAsString() const { char tmp[((CHAR_BIT * sizeof(int)) / 3 + 1)]; return itoa(m_value, tmp, 10); };

    inner_type GetValue() const { return m_value; };
    void SetValue(const inner_type & value) { m_value = value; };

    int GetMinValue() const { return m_minValue; };
    int GetMaxValue() const { return m_maxValue; };

private:
    inner_type m_value;
    int m_minValue;
    int m_maxValue;
};

class Property {
public:
    Property(std::auto_ptr<PropertyValue> value, bool visible)
    {
        m_value = value;
        m_isVisible = visible;
    }

    bool IsVisible() const { return m_isVisible; }
    void IsVisible(const bool val) { m_isVisible = val; }

    std::string GetValueAsString() const { return m_value->GetAsString(); };

    const PropertyValue & getValue() const { return (*m_value.get()); }

private:
    std::auto_ptr<PropertyValue> m_value;
    bool m_isVisible;
};

class PropertyFlavorA : public Property {
public:
    PropertyFlavorA(std::auto_ptr<PropertyValue> value, bool visible) : Property(value, visible)
    {
        value->IsReadOnly(true);
    };
};

class PropertyFlavorB : public Property {
public:
    PropertyFlavorB(std::auto_ptr<PropertyValue> value, bool visible) : Property(value, visible) {};
};
```

Comment: The real question is how you want to access values. Are you just exposing them in a GUI? When you have a "Key" do you know the "value" type?

Comment: I'm writing a DAL/ORM. So yes a GUI is the main domain that will use my library. I don't have real key-value pairs. I can however tell the values datatype from some kind of key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally decided to use a vector of [boost::variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/variant.html) in my `List` class. My `Property` class is now a template class where the template parameter is instantiated with subclasses of a `ValueType` class. The different flavors of `Properties` derive from the `Property` class.

Right now it seems that this approach fulfills all my initial requirements:

- It keeps the complexity of the interface low ✓
- Iterating over all `Properties` in `List`, and calling methods that both `Property` flavors support is possible by using [std::for_each](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/?kw=for_each) and [boost::apply_visitor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost/apply_visitor.html) ✓
- When having an instance of a `Property`, accessing its value in a type safe way is possible if my `Property` base class gives access to its `ValueType` member. ✓
- Use of dynamic_cast or similar constructs is not needed ✓

Any comments on this approach are still appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have answered your own question...

> Iterate over all `Properties` in `List`, and call methods that both `Property` flavors support.

This is [polymorphism](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/).

Both your flavours of `Properties` have a base class which has a virtual function(s), which your A and B `Property` classes override. You can then call the function from a base class pointer stored in a `List`.

Comment: I'm familiar with polymorphism. But polymorphism does not allow me to access the values of a property in a type safe way. Remember that they are of different types. even the same flavor of a property can have different value types.

Comment: @sigy: Fair enough, can you give us an example of your `Property` (I assume Class?). Can you make your `Property` Class somewhat like a [Variant data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd338762.aspx)?