# dynamic_cast vs virtual AsDerived method in base

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting

When trying to access derived class behaviour, the most common approach I read about is using `dynamic_cast`s, i.e. `dynamic_cast<DerivedA*>(BasePtr)->DerivedAOnlyMethod()`. This isn't really pretty, but everybody understands what's going on.

Now I'm working on a code where this conversion is handled by virtual functions exported to the base class, for each derived class, i.e.:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual DerivedA* AsDerivedA() { throw Exception("Not an A"); }
    virtual DerivedB* AsDerivedB() { throw Exception("Not a B"); }
    // etc.
};
class DerivedA : public Base
{
public:
    DerivedA* AsDerivedA() { return this; }
};
// etc.
```

Use is then `BasePtr->AsDerivedA()->DerivedAOnlyMethod()`. Imho, this clutters up the base class, and exposes knowledge about the derived classes it shouldn't need.

I'm too inexperienced to say with certainty which is better, so I'm looking for arguments for and against either construct. Which is more idiomatic? How do they compare regarding performance and safety?

Comment: These functions break the [open closed principle][1]. If you were to add a C class, you would need to change the Base class to add AsDerivedC.


  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, putting the `AsDerived@`-methods into the base-class certainly leads to potentially faster casting.

If you cap the inheritance-hierarchy using `final` that advantage might be reduced or removed though.

Also, you are right about it being uncommon because it introduces clutter, and it introduces knowledge of all relevant derived classes into the base-class.

In summary, it *might* sometimes be useful in a bottleneck, but you *will* pay for that abomination.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing more code it is difficult to offer too much advice. However, needing to know the type of the object you're calling into argues more for a variant than a polymorphic type.

polymorphism is about information hiding. The caller should not need to know what type he is holding.

something like this, perhaps?

```
struct base
{
    virtual bool can_do_x() const { return false; }
    virtual void do_x() { throw std::runtime_error("can't"); }
    virtual ~base() = default;
};

struct derived_a : base
{
    virtual bool can_do_x() const { return true; }
    virtual void do_x() { std::cout << "no problem!"; }
};

int main()
{
  std::unique_ptr<base> p = std::make_unique<derived_a>();
  if (p->can_do_x()) {
    p->do_x();
  }
}
```

Now we're talking to the object in terms of capabilities, not types.

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is right, the `AsDerivedX` methods are clutter. The fact that at runtime it can be checked whether these virtual functions were overloaded is equivalent to the cost of a typecheck. So, in my opinion, the C++ way of doing this is:

```
void doSomething(Base *unsureWhichAorB) {
    DerivedA *dA = dynamic_cast<DerivedA*>(unsureWhichAorB);
    if(dA) //if the dynamic cast failed, then dA would be 0
       dA->DerivedAOnlyMethod();
}
```

Note that the check for non-zeroness of `dA` is critical here.

Answer (score 1):

You are totally correct that such a solution not only clutters the base class but also puts unnecessary dependencies on it. In a clean design the base class does not need to and actually should not know **anything** about its derived classes. Everything else will become a maintenance nightmare pretty soon.

However, I'd like to point out that I am in the "try to avoid `dynamic_cast`"-Team. Meaning that I often see `dynamic_cast` that could have been avoided with a proper design. So the question to ask in the first place would be: Why do I need to know the derived type? Usually there is either a way to solve the problem by using polymorphism correctly or "losing" the type information already was the wrong path.

Prefer to use polymorphism instead of `dynamic_cast`:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void doSomething() = 0;
};

class DerivedA : public Base
{
public:
    void doSomething() override { //do something the DerivedA-way };
};

class DerivedB : public Base
{
public:
    void doSomething() override { //do something the DerivedB-way };
};
// etc.
```

Comment: If the needed functions are polymorphic in behaviour, then they virtual functions in the base class. But sometimes you need derived class specific methods.

Comment: Then I would question the decision to assign them to a variable of type `Base`. If you - at some point - need to know the actual type why did you "throw it away" in the first place?

Comment: To store them in a common container.

Comment: I guessed so ;) But why do you need to do that? I mean obviously they are not all the same, so why pretend so? Maybe [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/variant.html) is a better option then?

Comment: I've read about `boost::variant`, and I'll think about it. For now, to not throw everything overboard, I'll stick with the casting. Thanks anyway, this was helpful.

Comment: You can also have a look at this old question of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21859424/design-alternative-for-access-to-derived-class-member-from-base-class-pointer